# Prove that both $A$ and $B$ are connected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two closed subsets of a topological space $X$ such that both $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are connected. Prove that both $A$ and $B$ are also connected.

My attempt:

> On the contrary, let us assume that $A$ is disconnected. Then there exist non-empty disjoint closed subsets $C$ and $D$ of $A$ such that $A = C \cup D.$

> Since $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ so are $C$ and $D$. Then both $C \cap B$ and $D \cap B$ are disjoint closed subsets of $A \cap B$. As  $A \cap B$ is connected, so at least one of $C \cap B$ or $D \cap B$ is empty.

> Now if $C \cap B = \emptyset$, then
> $$ A \cup B = (D \cup B) \cup C $$
> gives a disconnection of $A \cup B$, and if $D \cap B = \emptyset$, then
> $$ A \cup B = (C \cup B) \cup D$$
> gives a disconnection of $A \cup B$. So in any case we arrive at a contradiction. Hence $A$ has to be connected.

> By a similar argument we can prove that $B$ has to be connected and this completes the proof.

Now my question is "What will happen if we drop closedness of at least one of the sets $A$ or $B$?" Does the result still hold?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Also please check my proof whether it holds good or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only issue with your attempt is "Since $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ so are $C$ and $D$". This statement is not needed since $C, D$ are closed by assumption.

Regarding your other question, consider $(\mathbb R, \tau)$ with $A = (0,1)\cup (2,3)$, $B=[1,2]$. Then $A\cup B = (0,3)$ is connected, so is $A\cap B = \emptyset$ (vacuously) but $A$ is disconnected.

Comment: No they are closed subsets of $A$ (with respect to subspace topology). They might not be closed in $X$ unless $A$ was a closed subset of $X.$

Comment: Also if you omit that step then $C$ and $D$ might not be closed in $A \cup B.$ So we would not get a disconnection of $A \cup B$ as I have mentioned. Otherwise where is the use of closedness of $A$ and $B$ in the entire proof? Kindly check it again.